# Using of nouns VS using of gerunds

Tags: word-usage

If I am talking about the applications that correct grammars' errors, should I say "grammar correction application" or "grammar correcting application"?

Please justify the use of one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking *in general,* any which way is okay. After all, they are *sentences*. There is a *grammar-correction application* or *grammar-correcting application.* It is unambiguous. They'd serve as *compound adjectives/modifiers.*

Nevertheless, if it is a ***name*** of the application, I'd avoid using such words. Rather, I'd opt for a simple one - ***Grammar Checker***

Comment: What is the actual difference between the two examples that I mentioned in my question, i.e. what does each one describe?